# Any indication of what time it is at the end of the first "What If…?" episode?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel-what-if-2021

At the end of the first episode we see these characters,

> Nick Fury, Peggy Carter as Captain Carter, and Hawkeye.

Is there any indication of what the timeline is here?

> When Peggy comes out of the portal, persumably this would be pre-Avengers? As Captain America was a big part of forming the Avengers.

Bonus questions:

> Were Nick Fury and Hawkeye waiting for her there? Did they open the portal back up?
>  
>  How did they know she was alive still?
>  
>  Where are they?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think we can safely presume that this is an altered version of what we see in *The Avengers* where the Tesseract is used to open a portal and Loki comes through. Instead though SHIELD open the portal themselves and Captain Carter comes out. We can presume this because Nick says:

> **Nick Fury:** The War ended almost seventy years ago.
>
> <sub>*What If...?*, Season 1 Episode 1, “What If... Captain Carter Were The First Avenger?”</sub>

Assuming the war ends at the same time, which it probably would’ve done given what we saw, then almost seventy years ago would line up nicely with 2012. So we can then assume this is in the same SHIELD base. It is worth noting though that they didn’t know she was going to come through, Hawkeye tells Nick who she is and he looks surprised. It doesn't appear to have been a planned thing.

Comment: Also Fury has lost an eye. (Or he’s at least wearing a patch — maybe in this universe, that’s just a fashion choice.)

Comment: This answer is now backed up by the last episode of the season, in which we see that Captain Carter has followed exactly the same timeline as Captain America (in our universe).